# Adding to an already existing variable with two scripts and a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a leaderboard type system where you go see the leaderboard, go the the next scene where you can choose a winner, the winner then gets two points on the leaderboard and the loser gets one.

**Score.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text counterText;
    public float counter;
    public float counter2;
    public Text counterText2;
    public float counter3;
    private int counter3Int = 0;
    public Text counterText3;
    public float NSIX;

    public float Lose;
    public float Win;
    public Text LoseText;
    public Text WinText;

    public float GetMkwiiPoints()
    {
        return counter3Int;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        counter = 0;
        counter2 = 1;
        counter3 = counter3Int;
        NSIX = 60;
        counterText.text = counter.ToString();
        counterText.text = (int.Parse(counterText.text) + Mathf.FloorToInt(counter3 / NSIX)).ToString();
        Lose = FindObjectOfType<Winning>().Add1Dad();
        
    }

    public void Round1Dad()
    {
        counterText.text = (int.Parse(counterText.text) + Lose).ToString();
}

    public void CLICKTHIS()
    {
        counterText.text = (int.Parse(counterText.text) + counter2).ToString();
    }

    public static Score Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        Instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

**Winning.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Winning : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Add1;
    public float Add2;
    public Text Add1Text;
    public Text Add2Text;

    public float Add1Dad()
    {
        return Add1;
    }

    public float Add2Dad()
    {
        return Add2;
    }
}
```

I have made a button that can add 1 to the score when I click it (counter2) and that works perfectly fine when in the same scene, but when I use the DontDestryOnLoad thing the button that I have `Score.cs` assigned to destroys itself because of that code, which is why I want to do it with two scripts. I hope I explained it well enough

Comment: You always destroy the object holding the script - `Destroy(gameObject);`. Remove this.